# PHP replace web address test in variable

Tags: php, variables, replace

can anyone help with this? I have a web address as a variable and would like to replace multiple web address if they exist.

```
$value = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
: "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Say if part of the URLs exist within the variable, then replace with a different one. Maybe str_replace would be the best way but unsure how to do it with more than one possibility.

ie. If the following are to be stored, store https://www.url4.com/ instead.

https://www.url1.com/

https://www.url2.com/hello/

https://www.url3/

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to give proper solution. Do you want to change the domain alone or domain with URI values?

Comment: it's to change the sigle value in the variable. If either exist then replace them with something else. Hope that is clearer.

Comment: No. lets try with example. You have an URL "https://www.url2.com/hello/" and you need to change as "https://www.url4.com/hello/" or "https://www.url4.com/"? This is my question ..

Comment: lets say change it to "url4.com"

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found and the best way I have found.

```
setcookie($cookie_name, strstr($value, '/url-folder')
```

When setting the cookie use strstr which will remove everything before.

In my case this is being stored in a cookie and only require part of the URL. when echo the link concatenate the new address followed by the cookie value.